# How to place the label in the exact position even after adjusting the screen in asp .net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Below is my code for displaying the tabs exactly to the system's screen if i am viewing it in my pc with full width[actual image when the width is full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Mm3.png) and if i am restoring the screen my tabs are becoming in this way [when i click on the icon which is left to x in browser my tabs are getting modified in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfDM2.png)How can i keep my tabs exact position even when restoring.

```
 Below is my menu css
         .wrapper {
        width:1335px;
        margin:auto;
        position:fixed;
    }   
    .menu {
        background-color: rgb(10,110,178);
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px 0px 10px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 40px;
        color: rgb(243,243,243);
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
         clear:both;
        /*height: 2.9em;*/
        position:fixed;
        /*background-color:#6DBDD6;*/
        z-index:1;
       /*padding-top: 10px;*/
        /*text-align: center;*/
    }
    .navigation_first_item {
    border-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

    .navitem_s {
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid rgb(10,85,125);
        border-left: 1px solid rgb(67,153,200);
        height: 40px;
        background-color: rgb(14,79,114);
    }
    .menu ul {
    }
    .menu ul li {
            float:left;
            display:block;
            list-style:none;
            border-right:1px solid rgb(10,85,125);
            border-left:1px solid rgb(67,153,200);

    }
    .menu ul li.navigation_first_item:hover {
                border-radius:5px 0px 0px 5px;
    }
    .menu ul li a {
        font-size:13px;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:40px;
        padding:8px 20px;
        color:rgb(255,255,255);
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    .menu ul li:hover {
            background-color: rgb(14,79,114);
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(14,89,130);

    }
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }



    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu">
                 <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="MenuFileUpload" runat="server"><a href="FileUpload.aspx">File Upload</a></li>
                         <li id="MenuReports" runat="server"><a href="Reports.aspx" id="Rpf" runat="server">Reports</a></li>
                         <li id="lichangepwd" runat="server"><a id="A1" href="ChangePassword.aspx" runat="server">Change Password</a></li>
                        <%--<div style="width:auto;float:right;font-weight:bold;padding-right:0cm;">--%>
                         <li id="lilogout" runat="server" style="float:right" ><a id="A2" href="Login.aspx" runat="server"> Logout</a></li><%--</div>--%>
                        <li><a>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" BorderColor="White" Text="Label" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
                            </a></li>
                    </ul>

                 </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can set a min width to the div they are in

Comment: i had done but its not working could you please help me out

Comment: can you share the wrapper class?

Comment: yes i will share you .wrapper {
    width:1335px;
    margin:auto;
    position:fixed;
}

Comment: along with wrapper class i had shared the css of listitems also by editing my original post because the list item logout and label are being changed on restoring(compressing the screen width of the browser)

Answer (score 1):

as Ferus said Add min-width to menu class with !important to make sure its applied.

> ```
> .menu{
> // Existing styles
> min-width: 600px !important;
> }
> ```

Using min width is not recommended, specially when you are designing a responsive layout. 
Try bootstrap this will manage most of the stuff for you. for more detail visit http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: on taking width:600px it is occupying only half of the web page

Comment: Basically width will be 100%, measure the min-width that you want to keep as minimum. min-width would be the width where your elements come on the next line for example 600px. I have edited the answer with more detail.